# How Can I Pass a Multi Argument Function with an Array? - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, opengl, floating-point

I am trying to pass an array containing an X, Y, and Z coordinate (type float) to the function glTranslatef() however I can't figure out a way to accomplish this.

As an example of what I am trying to accomplish;

```
float xyz[3] = {3,2,1};
glTranslatef(xyz);
```

I get the following error whenever I try to attempt something like this

> cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘GLfloat {aka float}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void glTranslatef(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat)’

I have tried searching all over google but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: So, you're looking for a C++ equivalent to Python's `func(*args)` syntax?

Comment: Do not use ALL UPPERCASE names, except for macros, where you should use them.

Comment: @ Alf P. Steinbach That's not my real code, it's just an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glTranslatef` takes three `float` arguments, not one array argument. That's the end of it.

```
float XYZ[3] = {3,2,1};
glTranslatef(XYZ[0], XYZ[1], XYZ[2]);
```

If you're really desperate you can unpack it with a macro:

```
#define UNPACK_TRI_ARRAY(ar) ar[0], ar[1], ar[2]

float XYZ[3] = {3,2,1};
glTranslatef(UNPACK_TRI_ARRAY(XYZ));
```

But once you get to that point, you have to ask yourself *why*.

Comment: Ok, I just remember in some point in time (I don't even remember what language I was using) being able to accomplish this without having to repetitively and separately define the location in the array.

Comment: @MarkData: Maybe you were thinking about glVertexfv, glNormalfv, etc. which indeed take a vector/array.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately there is no `v` variant for `glTranslatef`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
glTranslatef(XYZ[0], XYZ[1], XYZ[2]);
```

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml

Prototype:

```
void glTranslatef(GLfloat   x,
                  GLfloat   y,
                  GLfloat   z);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
glTranslatef(XYZ[0], XYZ[1], XYZ[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I'd just define an overload for the function taking a `const float *` and then pass array elements to the original three-arguments (X,Y,Z) function.

Comment: Why not a `const float (&)[3]`?